# system function on windows 7 failed with access denied error

Tags: c++, windows, function, permissions, system

I am writing a simple c++ app in visual studio 2012 on windows 7 wherein I am using the system command, strangely the system command fails with access denied error. For ex, I am trying to create a directory using system("mkdir C:\abc"), the command fails and the errno is set to EACCESS. 
Though I fail to create a new directory programmatically, I can very well create a new directory through the command prompt or through explorer.
Also, the CreateDirectory Windows API works fine, it is the system function that is the issue - because no matter what command I pass to the system function, it fails with the same error EACCESS.

I have also noticed that this is machine specific, running the same program on a different machine is no issue.

Any ideas what could be going wrong on this unfortunate machine.

Things that I have already tried
1) Setting administrator privileges on the application
2) ran the system file checker - no problem detected
3) disable avast

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `system` uses `%ComSpec% /c` to execute the command. The default `ComSpec` value is `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`. What's the value of this environment variable in your app?

Comment: If %comspec% isn't the problem (though I suspect that it is) it may be worth using Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to see if you can identify what the system is doing when the system() function fails.

Comment: @eryksun : echo %COMSPEC% returns "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" and echo %SystemRoot% return "C:\WIndows" - tried from command prompt and through the C++ application.

Comment: @HarryJohnston : thanks for mentioning process monitor, I digged a bit into the process monitor logs and realised that the cmd.exe under "C:/windows/syswow64/cmd.exe" is being referenced instead of the one under "c:/windows/system32" (I am not sure why). When I tried running the cmd.exe under syswow64 it failed with the error "a device attached to the system is not working". Googling a bit on this showed up some link with virus and or anti-virus software. So I updated my avast anti virus software and restarted the computer and voila it all worked fine. Thanks so much to you both.

Comment: @HarryJohnston : I am not able to mark your reply as answer.

Comment: Your application is 32-bit, so accessing the `System32` directory gets redirected to `SysWow64`. The native 64-bit directory is available as `Sysnative`.

Comment: You did the work, I suggest you answer the question yourself.